# How to Restrict Ctrl + End in an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have some data inserted at Rows 500 - 503. I placed the data intentionally at those rows because these rows will be used in Macro's and not for User's view. The data concerned to the user ends at Row 100.

I have hidden the Rows 500 - 503, yet after hitting Ctrl + End, the Cursor moves to Row 499.

My requirement is after hitting Ctrl + End, the Cursor should be at the last cell of Row 100.

So, how do i do this ?

*EDIT : Thanks for all the answers. Many advised me to have another sheet for non user related data, but i can't have it. Also i am not supposed to have the vba scripts.(Should have given you these conditions before... my bad!)*

Comment: `Many advised me to have another sheet for non user related data, but i can't have it. ` ... but that's the answer you accepted?!

Comment: @Jean : Yes i did, as it is a clean solution in any case. But if my conditions are taken into consideration, other work around's needs to be done (in fact, i thought i can even accept other answers too, but can't :(, which are the work around's)

Comment: @MSK you may change your mind later on and select a more relevant answer. In addition or if you don't want to reposition the green hook, you can acknowledge secondary answers by upvoting them and eventually leaving a comment

Comment: The following link gives a clear and concise way of reseting the "Used Range" through a SIMPLE macro. And I learned that you can even put a specific macro on your shortcut toolbar so it can be used across various excel files! http://www.techrepublic.com/article/reset-the-last-cell-of-your-excel-worksheet/6135485

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem will be removed with better isolation.

That is, worksheets which are designed for use by a user should be restricted to containing only the elements necessary for the user interface. In this case, only the rows which the user is supposed to see.

Any data which needs to be persisted in worksheets which is not designed for direct user consumption should be on their own worksheets, which can even be hidden from the user completely.

Comment: +1 I like this ansewr because it clearly shows that and how you can use Excel in a non - assulting way. As to the constraints mentioned by MSK this for me is primarily a question of ownership. If you find something useful and you are the owner of the sheet, just do it. If not get the owner to do it or give you the mandate to do it on his/her behalf. Let's not forget ... in the end it's Office Automation only. Any sheet will survive in a business process without macro's and gadgets and maybe put a bit more load on the user.

Answer (score 5):

The specific answer to your question of course is: trap the usage of the Ctrl-END key.

You can do this easily by specifying the following event triggers to your sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^{END}", "SuppressMe"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^{END}", ""
End Sub
```

and another module containing

```
Sub SuppressMe()
    ' you can be very creative here about line 100 or not 100
    MsgBox "Co-Cooooo :-P"
End Sub
```

Another cute way meeting the requirements you described and eliminating the need of watching and suppressing keys would be to limit navigation to row 100. Now a Ctrl-END would place the user into the rightmost column of row 100, and Ctrl-DOWN would be covered as well. In fact the user just can't go past row 100

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 100 Then
        Me.Cells(100, Target.Column).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

but .... wait !!! is there really no way? ... of course the user still may SCROLL past row 100 and detect your little row-500 easter egg. So I concur to 100% with earlier suggestions about a different strategy, because

- a user finding out that exactly line 500 - 503 is hidden can become tremendeously curious about the why's
- Ctrl-END is not the only way the user can navigate past row 100 - you would need to suppress END-DOWN (a 2 - key combination ... you need to buffer the END and ask the next key: are you a DOWN ... have fun!)
- and you are wasting disk space to store a sheet with so many blank rows just for that line 500

You may have reasons to implement a key supressor, but always remember there are many different ways for the user to bypass it and this needs to be considered very carefully.

Comment: Which make me think - white-text-on-white-background may elicit less suspicion than hidden lines, however stupid that may sound.

Comment: @Jean : Would like to know why the question is awful :)

Comment: @Jourbac: not stupid at all, indeed I am using this on a certain occasion with great success and user acceptance

Comment: @Jean: I feel honored; must have done something right then ;-)

Comment: @MSK: Well, it isn't as much the question itself as what the question asks us to do! Ick! Also there wasn't any indication of why you wanted to do this (which would allow us to suggest alternative solutions) and now I can see that you omitted a couple of important details.

Answer (score 3):

That's Excel's built-in behaviour, and I don't think you can change it. Suggestions:

- Put your hidden data on another sheet of the same workbook. This is really the cleanest way to work.
- Alternatively, navigate using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Down arrow</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd><kbd>Down arrow</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

As others said it's certainly better to separate your non-user data on a different sheet.

That said, one thing you could do is protect your sheet and disallow access to locked cells, leaving only the cells in which the user has to input something unlocked.

Doing that prevents <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> from doing anything at all: it can't jump to the last cell as it is locked, so it doesn't do anything. (Tested on Excel 2007)

But again, you'll probably be better off by separating user and non-user data in different sheets.